# Although I write the necessary codes, I can't get results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intellij-idea

*Laptop text and price should appear on the blue button.
Although I write the necessary codes, I can't get results*

```
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap"/>
  <div class="card-body" >
    <h5 class="card-title">
      {{product.name}} {{product.price | currency:'USD':true:"1.2-2"}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          {{product.description}}
        </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go Somewhere</a>
  </div>
```

and **product.price** I get an error
**no code errors, can't see in browser**

[image]

It should have written where I marked what the above code requires

.ts code

```
  export class Product{
  id:number;
  name: string;
  price:number;
  categoryId:number;
  description:string;
  imageUrl:string;
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the error that you get in the question's body?

Comment: Please add code snippet so we can trace the issue.

Comment: no code errors, can't see in browser

Comment: Add your .ts code

Comment: export class Product{
  id:number;
  name: string;
  price:number;
  categoryId:number;
  description:string;
  imageUrl:string;
}

Comment: You should add the .ts code that's behind your html code and not just the product class. E.g. if your html is in myComponent.html, we need the myComponent.ts content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you should check:

- Do the `<h5>` `<p>` tags exist in the inspector (browser development tools)?
- Are you sure the css doesn't hide the elements for some reason? e.g. Change the line `{{product.name}} {{product.price | currency:'USD':true:"1.2-2"}}</h5>` to `{{product.name}} {{product.price | currency:'USD':true:"1.2-2"}}TEST</h5>` - Does TEST show up? if yes, css should be fine
- If the above points are ok, I suspect that product or product.name/product.currency are undefined. Maybe add a `this.product.name='test';` in your component to make sure it has a value

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying right now. Thank you for your kind reply.